# A While loop where the loop clause can receive problematic input

Tags: warning-messages

Consider the following highly artificial example:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
While[Length[list[[1]]] > 3,
  If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 0.2,
    list = {};
    ,
    list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}};
    ];
];
```

Some 20% of the time here, you'll see the error:

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist. >>
```

How can we avoid this error if we are only allowed to modify the clause in the While loop and must have the `Length[list[[1]]] > 3` query somewhere in the clause statement?  Can we have an incident where `list = {}` cause a termination of the loop or ask for this to satisfy the loop clause?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! To interact better with this site it is recommended to register your account.  I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the faq! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
While[list =!= {} && Length[list[[1]]] > 3, 
  If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 0.2, list = {};, list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}};];];

list
(* {{1,2,3},{}} *)
```

or

```
ClearAll[list];
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
While[Length[list[[1]]] > 3, 
  If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 0.2, Break[], list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}};];];

list
(* {{1,2,3},{}} *)
```

or

```
ClearAll[list];
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
Catch[While[Length[list[[1]]] > 3, 
   If[RandomReal[{0, 1}] < 0.2, Throw[{}];, list = {{1, 2, 3}, {}};];]];

list
(* {{1,2,3},{}} *)
```